# Can you rename squads in Into The Breach?

Tags: into-the-breach

Most of the mech squads have fitting, nice names such as the Steel Judoka or the Frozen Titans. However, when playing as a Random or Custom squad, the name is simply "Time Travelers", which is a little boring.

Since it's possible to rename mechs and pilots, I was expecting it possible to rename squads as well, but I can't find any way to do so. So is there any way to rename a squad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot rename squads at the moment, but one of the developers has added it to a list of player suggestions that they will consider.

Source:
https://www.reddit.com/r/IntoTheBreach/comments/811hkh/discussion_why_cant_we_rename_our_squads/